# Difference between a prediction and estimate-linear regression

Tags: linear-model, prediction

I have a regression equation ( y =-62,125 +10.86x) . y = kilowatts/electricity and temperature =x and these two questions sound completely identical . what is the difference in calculating the answer? Im assuming Q3 involves the error ... but in reality I'm really confused and could do with some help , cheers. questions are here

Q3 Find an estimate for the mean amount of electricity used when the temperature is 95F? Q4 Predict the amount of electricity that would be used when the temperature is 95F?

Comment: Please tag your question `self-study`

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, as you're not told what the study units are on which the x and y variables are measured. But let's say that the study units are homes in a particular geographic area such that for each home you measure the amount of electricity used and the outside temperature on a set day. Let's also say that the study which generated the data used to derive the regression equation included only 100 homes, selected at random from that region.

For your Q3, what you need to estimate is the mean amount of electricity used by ALL homes in the geographic area of interest for which the outside temperature was 95F.

For your Q4, what you need to predict is the amount of electricity that would be used by a randomly selected home from the geographic area of interest for which we would know the outside temperature to be 95F. (This new home would be different from the 100 homes already included in the study.)

It turns out that the answer to both questions is the same! But if you wish to attach a measure of uncertainty to your answer by reporting a 95% confidence interval for Q3 and a 95% prediction interval for Q4, the widths of the two intervals will be different. The prediction interval will be wider than the confidence interval!